# ubuntu 16.04 not booting any more

Tags: dual-boot, 16.04

I have installed ubuntu 16.04 and windows 10 in dual boot mode and it was working all fine till this morning but suddenly everything on terminal started giving an input /output error. i tried everything out on foums.but now the ubuntu has stop loading. is there any way by which i can correct my ubuntu and make it work again , my windows 10 is working fine,maybe anyone knows some tool which may help to repair the drive.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Could you paste error logs ?
When booting, you can try to check your disk if it comes from it, but certainly not, as your Windows is still OK.
You might have to reinstall your system; don't forget to backup your Ubuntu data before doing that (external HD, for example).